# Could not start Node.js server on Drupal 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, npm, drupal

When I try to start node.js on my server, it does not work. I think I have correctly configured the module. What's wrong ?

Here are the error messages in the terminal :

```
root@vps000000:/home/www.s1biose.com/public_html/node_modules/drupal-node.js# node app.js
fs.js:646
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ''
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at Object.server.start (/home/www.s1biose.com/public_html/node_modules/drupal-node.js/lib/server.js:74:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/www.s1biose.com/public_html/node_modules/drupal-node.js/app.js:15:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
```

Here is the configuration of the file nodejs.config.js

```
settings = {
  scheme: 'https',
  port: 443,
  host: 'www.s1biose.com',
  resource: '/socket.io',
  serviceKey: 'hgfjkliutfh',
  backend: {
    port: 443,
    host: 'www.s1biose.com',
    scheme: 'https',
    basePath: '/web',
    messagePath: '/nodejs/message'
  },
  debug: false,
  sslKeyPath: '',
  sslCertPath: '',
  sslCAPath: '',
  baseAuthPath: '/nodejs/',
  extensions: [],
  clientsCanWriteToChannels: false,
  clientsCanWriteToClients: false,
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  jsMinification: true,
  jsEtag: true,
  logLevel: 1
};
```

Comment: Can't provide much help with just a config file to work with.

Comment: @thomann061 Here is the problem that I opened https://github.com/beejeebus/drupal-nodejs/issues/31

Comment: @thomann061 the configuration of my server is here https://www.drupal.org/project/nodejs/issues/2948772